# How to fit polynomial function to time series data that minimizes least square error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scipy

I have time series data. I want to group the data in 10 minute bins and I want to fit polynomial functions to each of the 10 minute bins that minimize that least square errors.
So, from 15:20 to 15:30 would be one bin and have its own polynomial function, from 15:30 to 15:40 would be another bin and have its own polynomial function, etc.

I am lost here and I need guidance.

```
df    
time     var
15:21    56
15:22    99
15:23    105
..     ...
18:45    132
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. Here is one:

```
def convertToMinutes( hhmm:str):
  parts = hhmm.split(':')
  return int( parts[0])*24 + int( parts[1])

def parseLine( line):
  parts = line.split()
  minutes = convertToMinutes( parts[0])
  var = int(parts[1])
  return minutes, var

def polyRegression( tuples:list):
  # each tuple contain time (in minutes) and value
  # number of tuples is (len(tuples))
  # algorithm: to be defined
  pass

tb = []
previousIndex = 0 # index into tb
lines = open( filename, 'r')
for i,line in enumerate( lines):
  tb.append( parseLine( line))
  if (tb[i][0] // 10) != (tb[previousIndex][0] // 10):
    # this new line is in a different bin. Process the previous bin.
    if (i - previousIndex) >= 1:
      print( polyRegression( tb[previousIndex:i]))
    previousIndex = i
if (i - previousIndex) >= 1:
  # the last bin is not processed
  print( polyRegression( tb[previousIndex:i]))
```

You will have to define the datafile name.
I assumed that the datafile will not span more that one day.
The code shown will work even if there is more than one day but may not work if you skip a day.

Please note that after processing a bin, 'i' will be equal to 'previousIndex'.
So 'i - previousIndex' == 0 means that there is one tuple not processed.
Also, the polynomial regression is not executed if we have less than 2 tuples in a bin.

Comment: thank you, i'm trying to implement your solution but i am getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'time, var'". I tried removing the column names and just kept the values but then: same error with: "21, 56". (minute and value in row 1). 
How can I implement this for a csv file? Also, if the time is in the datetime format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" with many days of data?

Comment: I assumed the the datafile had no headers, but if you need them, it's possible to modify the program. The "parseLine" function expect a time column with hours and minutes (as in your example in the question). In which line do you get ValueError? Don't bother with CSV unless it's the native datafile format. And, yes, it possible to accept a full datetime format. Please define your needs.